# GCP Ingress - Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: cloud armor security policies not supported for regional backend service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I've got this issue in Google cloud once tried to create an ingress resource.

Usually when ingress is created, other GCP resources are automatically created too (resources such as target-https-proxies-list , urlmap , forwarding-rules , etc. ). Nothing was created this time and the Ingress error is here:

```
k describe ingress my-service-internal
Name:             my-service-internal
Namespace:        my-namespace
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.0.0.5:8080)
Rules:
  Host                                     Path  Backends
  ----                                     ----  --------
  my-service.example.com
                                           /*   my-service-internal:80 (10.251.1.108:8080,10.251.1.134:8080)
Annotations:                               ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: my-certificate-202107140101
                                           kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
                                           kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-internal
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                 From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----                ----                     -------
  Normal   Sync    97s (x2 over 97s)   loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Warning  Sync    16s (x14 over 73s)  loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: cloud armor security policies not supported for regional backend service k8s1-263259a6-my-namespace-my-service-in-8-151d5ee9
```

Any advice what to check first or any guesses what could be the issue?

Comment: My guess would be that **Internal** `Ingress` does not support the `Cloud Armor` policies: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features.

Comment: Hi @laimison any progress? Did Dawid's suggestion help you?

Comment: hi @Mikolaj I had to switch to another tasks today, unfortunately. I have added to my notes to update SO once the issue is solved as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing reference to security policy in a backendconfig.

Changing from

```
Spec:
  Connection Draining:
    Draining Timeout Sec:  60
  Security Policy:
    Name:  
  Session Affinity:
    Affinity Type:  NONE
  Timeout Sec:      40
```

To

```
Spec:
  Connection Draining:
    Draining Timeout Sec:  60
  Session Affinity:
    Affinity Type:  NONE
  Timeout Sec:      40
```

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a bit more on Dawids answer:

The reason for this is that cloud armor policies are only usable by **external HTTP** loadBalancers
as explained on [Google's documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview?hl=en#requirements)

So if you are configuring an [internal ingress on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress?hl=en#requirements) this creates an **Internal HTTP** LoadBalancer, which is not compatible with Cloud armor security policies